# Voice Capabilities in Android Wear

Tags: android, wear-os

I am trying to add Voice Capabilities in Android Wear and following below URL

https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/voice.html

Here is my manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.demowearapp"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.type.watch" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="20"
        android:targetSdkVersion="20" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".TaxiActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.actions.RESERVE_TAXI_RESERVATION" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

But when i am trying below voice commands in my LG G watch it doesn't open my activity...it just showing Google search results

**"OK Google, get me a taxi"**

**"OK Google, call me a car"**

Thanks.

Comment: I've the category default that you removed and also I have the metadata for gms version: https://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html (using play-services-wearable as dependency)

Comment: @jush your solution doesn't work. Am wondering why wear app needs google-play-services for voice capabilities.

Answer (score 0):

The wearable doesn't know this is a wear app. Wear apps need this in their manifest: `<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.type.watch" />`

Comment: Thanks for your response, but it doesn't work event after adding "android.hardware.type.watch"

Comment: Also, try removing `<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />`. The voice capabilities page doesn't list this as being a part of this voice action.

Comment: Out of curiosity, if you say "Ok Google, open {App Name}", does the activity launch?

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem. The solution was to add the category `android.intent.category.DEFAULT` to the intent filter:

```
    <activity android:name=".TaxiActivity" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.actions.RESERVE_TAXI_RESERVATION" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

If you open the Android Wear app on the phone you can verify that your app is available under "Call a car" beneath "Voice actions".

For non-English speakers still having problems using the voice command you should double check the language used for voice commands on your device. Change it to English and try it out. If that still doesn't work you can try changing the device's language to English also.