# Voice commands does not work on android gear

Tags: android, wear-os

I'm doing a really easy android wear app, that open with a voice command. I've tried with start {label} and with an action as call a taxi, but didn't work, I'm missing somthing.

I added this one on my wear manifest (is this correct?) and I deployed on the wear and on the phone.

the manifest code is:

```
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.karumi.kittwear" >

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.type.watch" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault" >
      <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
      <activity
            android:name="WearMainActivity"
            android:label="kit" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

      <activity
          android:name=".StartSearchMyCar">
        <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.actions.RESERVE_TAXI_RESERVATION" />
        </intent-filter>
      </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: i too having the similar problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25928594/voice-capabilities-in-android-wear

Comment: know it's working, the problem that I have it's the documentation it's bad, for spanish language, the voice commands are: 'abrir' for start command. and taxi reservartion doesn't exist on spanish :S

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem. The solution was to add the category `android.intent.category.DEFAULT` to the intent filter:

```
    <activity android:name=".StartSearchMyCar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.actions.RESERVE_TAXI_RESERVATION" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

If you open the Android Wear app on the phone you can verify that your app is available under "Call a car" beneath "Voice actions".

For other non-English speakers still having problems using the voice command you should double check the language used for voice commands on your device. Change it to English and try it out. If that still doesn't work you can try changing the device's language to English also.

Answer (score 0):

I have same issue: `OK Google, call me a taxi` does not work.

I made a workaround: I've named my app `taxi`, so now it`s sometimes launched when I say:`
OK Google, start taxi`.

Comment: Yeah, that is a solution. Do you try the command 'call a car?' is it working perfect for me.